# Job instantiation failed in java spring boot and Quartz

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I wanna use quartz in my java spring boot project, but
I have this error when call `scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);`:

org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:47)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:392)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.kian.trade.virtualbroker.service.impl.BrokerMessagingJob.()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:190)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.createJobInstance(AdaptableJobFactory.java:61)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:43)
... 2 common frames omitted

I config my project here and you can see it :

```
package com.kian.trade.virtualbroker.config;

import org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ReschedulingIntervalProperties.class)
public class QuartzConfig {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private final String orderResolutionThreadCount;
    private final String brokerMessagingThreadCount;
    private final String driverDelegateClass;

    @Autowired
    public QuartzConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                        @Value("${spring.quartz.order-resolution.threadCount}") String orderResolutionThreadCount,
                        @Value("${spring.quartz.broker-messaging.threadCount}") String brokerMessagingThreadCount,
                        @Value("${spring.quartz.driverDelegateClass}") String driverDelegateClass) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.orderResolutionThreadCount = orderResolutionThreadCount;
        this.brokerMessagingThreadCount = brokerMessagingThreadCount;
        this.driverDelegateClass = driverDelegateClass;
    }

    @Bean("order-resolution-scheduler")
    public SchedulerFactoryBean orderResolutionSchedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        scheduler.setAutoStartup(true);
        scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
        scheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzOrderResolutionProperties());
        scheduler.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
        scheduler.setJobFactory(beanJobFactory());

        return scheduler;
    }

    @Bean("broker-messaging-scheduler")
    public SchedulerFactoryBean brokerMessagingSchedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        scheduler.setAutoStartup(true);
        scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
        scheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzBrokerMessagingProperties());
        scheduler.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
        scheduler.setJobFactory(beanJobFactory());

        return scheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory beanJobFactory() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }


    public Properties quartzOrderResolutionProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz-order-resolution.properties"));

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", orderResolutionThreadCount);
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.".concat(driverDelegateClass));
        propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(properties);

        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public Properties quartzBrokerMessagingProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz-broker-messaging.properties"));

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", brokerMessagingThreadCount);
        properties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.".concat(driverDelegateClass));
        propertiesFactoryBean.setProperties(properties);

        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    private class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
            beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
            final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
            beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
            return job;
        }
    }




}
```

it is create a job and insert it into database with error satatus.
could you help me please to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the `jobDetail` you pass?

Comment: @tgdavies it is not depond on detail, error is Job instantiation failed

Comment: Try giving your job a default constructor.

Comment: can you explain it more?

Comment: When you read the stack trace, what do you think the ultimate cause of the exception is?